# Ways to use OOP principles to organise code for web application?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, oop, web

I'm designing my first web application and I'm looking for some advice on how to implement oop principles into it.

Basically, the app consists of a number of cascading dropdown selects that use Jquery ajax to populate the options in order to build an sql statement to return a specific set of data (including performing some calculations).

The way I have it structured so far is a number of JS functions in a script tag for the ajax calls with corresponding event handlers. For example:

```
$('#show_result').on('click', getResult);

function getResult() {
    alert( "Results displayed" );

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "calc_php/get_results.php", 
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#texty").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

and then a number of php includes files, for example:

```
<?php
    include '../../database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY country_id;';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['descrp'].'</option>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

I know that for an application this small, oop probably isn't necessary, however in the interested of learning, can anyone suggest the direction I might take to use oop in this? The only vague bit i've got is a class for the database connections:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $dbName = 'web_app' ;
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'root';
    private static $dbUserPassword = '**NotThatStupid**';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
       // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {     
        try
        {
          self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          die($e->getMessage()); 
        }
       }
       return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

Any advice or pointers will be gratefully received! :)

Comment: A general OOP  tutorial for PHP and JavaScript combined is a bit out of scope for SO.

Comment: Appreciated -  sorry my first question. Although, to be fair I'm not looking for a tutorial, just some pointers as to where to go from here :)

Comment: [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be appropriate, and/or you can search meta for [where to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+to+ask)

Comment: @StephenP when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) (wrt this question, over there it would likely be closed as duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260))

Answer (score -2):

Your php `Database` class is more like a utility class.

When thinking in OOP principles, think of your data as objects, and design what their properties and methods would be.

For example, in your table row retrieval

```
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['descrp'].'</option>';
    }
```

it could help to define a class of what each row *is*

```
<?php
class Country
{
    public $country_id;
    public $description;

    public function __construct($props) {
      $this->country_id = $props['country_id'];
      $this->description = $props['description'];
    }

    public function renderOption()
    {
      return '<option value="'.$this->country_id.'">'.$this->country_id.'</option>';
    }

}
?>
```

then when you need to render it

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $country = new Country($row);
    echo $country->render();
}
```

hopefully this can get you started with thinking in OOP.
and as you get more comfortable, since you are creating objects with data derived from a database, you'll want to look into using an ORM.